# where clause to get records which matches upto 2 decimal

Tags: mysql, sql, floating-point, decimal, where-clause

I have table containing following values:
colname:
28.54617,
28.54917,
98.54617,
48.54217,
28.54217

How can I write condition in where clause to fetch all records which match up to two decimal
so here expected output is:
28.54617,28.54917,28.54217

I want all rows which match this where clause, if I do 'colName' = '28.54617', it will just return 1 row as it will do an exact match of float, instead I want all rows which match up to 2 decimal of input value. In this case, input value would be 28.54617. Thanks

Comment: 2 approaches: **Arithmetic**, `|lookup - colname[i]| <= 0.01`.  This will get near to OP's goal.  **Text** Perform `|lookup - colname[i]| <= 0.02` (filter  out distant ones) and text (to 2 decimal places) compare.

Comment: The data must be truncated, not rounded? 28.54999 and 28.55000 are not in a group?

Comment: truncated is fine, should just compare first two decimal and if matches that should be part of query result.

Comment: "all records which match upto " -- Match WHAT?  Match "28.54"?  Match each other?

Answer (score 0):

If I'm not mistaken, you want columns that have been repeated more than once in the table before the decimal point.

`floor()` **function** The part before the decimal point gives the number.

```
select t2.val
from
  (select floor(val) as val
  from numTable
  group by floor(val)
  Having count(*) > 1) t1 join numTable t2 on t1.val = floor(t2.val)
```

demo in [*db<>fiddle*](https://dbfiddle.uk/?rdbms=mysql_5.7&fiddle=ec2715bb7a3f1d354022c1669b883e47)

Comment: I want all rows which matches this where clause, if I do 'colName' = '28.54617', it will just return 1 row as it will do exact match of float, instead I want all rows which matches uptol 2 decimal of input value. In this case input value would be 28.54617. Thanks

Comment: I still do not understand can enter the data table and desired  output?

Answer (score 0):

Use the function [`TRUNCATE()`](https://dev.mysql.com/doc/refman/8.0/en/mathematical-functions.html#function_truncate):

```
SELECT *
FROM tablename
WHERE TRUNCATE(col, 2) = 28.54
```

Or, if your input is a number like `28.54617`:

```
SELECT *
FROM tablename
WHERE TRUNCATE(col, 2) = TRUNCATE(28.54617, 2)
```

Change `col` to your column's name.